# Why emscripten emscripten_get_canvas_element_size does not return the DOM element size?

Tags: html5-canvas, emscripten

In the code of a big project using emscripten 2.0.8, a function tries to retrieve the size of the DOM element for a specific canvas in ordre to initialize.

```
double w=0, h=0;
emscripten_get_element_css_size(canvasCssSelector, &w, &h);
```

But I monitored the values with a log and they don't match at all with the size I get in my browser. Even more confusing, the size never changes while I do resize my window (and the canvas). It just stays constant to 300x150 (could be an initialization by code somewhere or default values, but it is still wrong regarding the actual DOM).

[Doc says](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html#c.emscripten_get_canvas_element_size)

> EMSCRIPTEN_RESULT emscripten_get_canvas_element_size(const char *target, int *width, int *height)
> Gets the current pixel width and height of the given Canvas element in the DOM.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57898301/1456761